# LAN connection says network cable is unplugged

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet

My Local Area Connection was working normally, but one day it broke.

I tried to fix it using another Internet cable but it is saying the same: *Network cable unplugged*.

I also tried the cable on another computer and it's working.

I also uninstalled the network card and restarted the computer.

Comment: First, what have you already tried to remedy this problem? Second, have you tried another cable yet?

Comment: yes i used another cable but it isn't working

Comment: cables are working normal different computer

Comment: Uninstall drivers of your network card from device manager and restart your computer then try.

Comment: thanks but after restart it is telling  same answer what should i do more

Comment: What does the other end of the network cable go to?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just found an answer on 2010 Kioskea that sounded too good to be true, unplug the power cord if it is a desktop or remove the battery of a notebook for 30 minutes. When I plugged my desktop back in the network worked perfectly.